# Specify height of UITableViewCell in search results

Tags: ios, uitableview

My UITableViewCells have a custom height of 120 points. I've just added a search bar and search results controller via Interface Builder. The search feature works. Only problem is the height of the UITableViewCells in the search results is smaller than 120 points (think its the default height).

**How can I specify the height of the cells in the search results?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively to Mark Adams suggestion, you can return 120 from within the delegate method `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` in the `searchResultsDelegate` property of the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `rowHeight` property on the `searchResultsTableView` property of `UISearchDisplayController`.